# designing table with a 3D effect

Tags: html, css

I try to do a little forum to train a little on web design. How can I change that table design to have a 3 dimensions (3D) table ? Or if there is any solution to improve its design, that will be maybe better !

Otherwise, any criticism is welcome!

[image]

```
/* Tableaux -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

pair {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

tr.impair {
    background-color: #fff;
}

th {
    color: #D89845;
    border: 1px solid #D89845;
    padding: 5px;
    font: normal 8pt verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
    font: normal 8pt verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

**PS:** I will keep the best suggestion as validation of the subject.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean have 3D borders, etc., have shadow or other visual effects or do you need a table with 3 dimensions - i.e. a 3D Table?  These are __very__ different things.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that sorry. Yes, 3D borders, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use box-shadow is the best solution to give any object a 3d look & feel.

> box-shadow use browser specipic prefixes like -webkit, -o, -moz etc . Here I just gave the link where you can find out more about it & can study how it works. I also many times just created such type of objects that have just 3d feel.
>   [Link to box-shadow](http://prashanttyagi923.blogspot.in/2012/11/box-shadow.html).

Comment: What do you think about of the rest of the design, please ?

Comment: By the way , I can give you the feedback about your page you designed if you will provide a link to that one. And what do you think about the answer is it acceptable for you or not ?, give a comment

Comment: i'm trying to figure out a nice using box-shadows, meanwhile i leave the topic open.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do anything with this,

```
    CSS:
.gridtable {
border:1px solid #000000;
height:149px;
width:342px;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
.fixedcell {
height:30px;
padding:0 2 0 2px;
background-color:#C2BFA5;
border-left:1px solid #E1E0D2;
border-top:1px solid #E1E0D2;
border-right:1px solid #8D8961;
border-bottom:1px solid #8D8961;
}
.gridcell {
height:30px;
background-color:#ffffff;
padding:0 2 0 2px;
border-right:1px solid #C0C0C0;
border-bottom:1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
```

**Edit**
Link to 3d effects : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp

Comment: Or look at over here there are some pretty looking examples:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp