# 3d borders on a html row

Tags: html, css, html-table

My pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/gimoI

I want to have a gray and white border on a table row to achieve a 3d effect.

Why is only one border color visible?

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;width:60px;">Alarm 1</td>
    <td style="width:auto;">
      <span style="font-weight:bold;">Brand LANG: </span>
      <span>Helmenstraße 5</span>
    <span>90000 Nürnbergxxxxxxxxx</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30px;text-align:center;"> <i class="icon-angle-down button"></i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:60px;vertical-align:top;">
      <div style="border-radius:28px;border:black solid 1px;background:red;">Alarm 1</div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:auto;">
      <span style="font-weight:bold;">Brand LANG: </span>
      <span>Langenburgerwald allee 25/c</span>
      <span>70000 Wurmlingen ob der Tauber</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30px;text-align:center;"> <i class="icon-angle-down button"></i></td>
  </tr> 
</table>

body,html{ 
  padding:0;
  margin:10px;
  background:#fafafa;  
}

table{

  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
}

table td
{
    padding: 5px;
}

td {
   border-bottom: gray solid 2px;
   border-top: white solid 2px;
  background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the top border is white and is difficult to see the diference with the background.

I just updated it now:

```
body,html{ 
  padding:0;
  margin:10px;
  background:#fcc;
}

table{

  border-spacing:0px;
}

table td
{
   padding: 5px;
   border-bottom: gray solid 2px;
   border-top: white solid 2px;
}

tr {

   background:green;

}
```

You have to remove border-collapse:collapse;

Check this [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vIHcf][1]

Comment: I checked your pen and I still only see the white border at the table top but not at the table rows!

Comment: oh... I edited your code sorry and havent seen your solution... now I see both borders! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with box shadows . I just also described it in my one of the answer of same type of questio [Link to that Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700559/designing-table-with-a-3d-effect) or you can go through to this link to learn more about box-shadows[Study box shadow](http://prashanttyagi923.blogspot.in/2012/11/box-shadow.html)

you can add

> -webkit-box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #595959; 
>  -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #595959; 
>  -o-box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #595959;

in your td style & then find that is it same as you want ..

Answer (score 0):

Both are visible on my side.

Little alternative or addition to achive 3d effects:

You can use CSS Outline. Its like a second border.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp

Answer (score 0):

I see the blank and grey border. But if you want to put some 3d effect on the rows why don't use box-shadow?

```
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #000;
```

[Here I made an example](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/9hnmq/) with your code.

Comment: Where do you see a RED and BLUE border on the same row? http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/gimoI please verify. I have updated my init question with a 3d border image sample how it should look like.

Comment: I've modified your code. I think that the error was at the table css declaration with the `border-collapse:collapse`. Now you can see the blue and red borders. [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/baJFf](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/baJFf)